# Doctrine: Validate Model Data using Annotations

Tags: validation, model, doctrine

In doctrine, is there a way that I could validate model data using annotations? Like the bellow example in c#

```
       public class ProductMD {
            [StringLength(50),Required]
            public object Name { get; set; }
            [StringLength(15)]
            public object Color { get; set; }
            [Range(0, 9999)]
            public object Weight { get; set; }
        }
```

So when the property Name is empty then it will give you error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, starting from Doctrine2 [there is no validation component integrated into the ORM itself anymore](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/13/doctrine2-validations.html).

If, for example, you're using Doctrine2 with Symfony2, you can take advantage of the [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html) framework component by using `@Assert` annotations in the Doctrine entities.

If you don't use any framework, or if the framework you use does not provide a validation component, you can always use Doctrine's lifecycle callbacks to provide custom validation in `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` (for more information, take a look [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/13/doctrine2-validations.html)). In this case, there's more manual work to be done but it still sounds like a reasonable solution.